# Getting all positions of an occuring String using StringBuilder.indexOf()

Tags: java, stringbuilder, indexof

Java Beginner over here.
I'm currently working on a programm that searches a part of the human DNA.
Specifically, I want to find all occurences of a String within a StingBuilder, using StringBuilder.indexOf(). But I need all occurences, not just the first.

Code:

```
public void search(String motive){
    int count = 0;
    gene.indexOf(motive);   // gene is the Stringbuilder
    count++;


}
```

I need all occurences of motive in the gene StringBuilder plus the counter how often motive is in gene.
Any help, since indexOf() only displays the first occurence?

Comment: Are there other `indexOf` methods in `StringBuilder`?

Comment: well, yes, there is `'indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)', but that isn't very helpful either, since I don't yet know where 'str' appears (obviously).

Comment: [Getting unix timestamp from Date()](//stackoverflow.com/q/7784421)

Comment: Then you start at 0. After that, you start 0+offset (which might be the length of the string), etc., etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that you are looking for indices of a specific nucleotide sequence within a gene sequence or sub-sequence. The following example class demonstrates a generic approach using Java's regular expression library to find such:

```
package jcc.tj.dnamatch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Gene {
   private String gene;

   public Gene() {}

   public Gene( String gene ) {
      this.gene = gene;
   }

   public List<Integer> find( String seq ) {
      List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( seq );
      Matcher m = pat.matcher( gene );

      while ( m.find() )
         indices.add( m.start() );

      return indices;
   }

   public String getGene() {
      return gene;
   }

   public void setGene( String gene ) {
      this.gene = gene;
   }
}
```

The above example, use a Matcher to find patterns. There are other String-based algorithms that may be more efficient, but as a starting point, the Matcher offers a generic solution to any type of text pattern search.

Encoding nucleotides as characters (ATCG) is very flexible and convenient, allowing the use of String-based tools to analyze and characterize sequences and/or sub-sequences. Unfortunately, they do not scale well. In such cases, it would be better to consider more specific bioinfomatics techniques for representing and managing sequences.

A good reference on certain techniques, would be Chapter 2 – Algorithms and Data Structures in Next-Generation Sequencing of the book [Next Generation Sequencing Technologies and Challenges in Sequence Assembly](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493907144). A more detailed PDF preview of it is available from [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx1fDY_63RAhUp54MKHZZyA-sQFgg3MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9781493907144-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1491490-p176604624&usg=AFQjCNHxSUyKT1e0p9xyIH-AqG-YwSp2ng&sig2=WNDx7c12nJmNwG5jh5DyFg) Google link; though I won't guarantee it to work forever.

You may also want to look at [BioJava](http://biojava.org/). While, I wouldn't want to detract you from Java, Perl is another good alternative for sequence analysis. [Beginning Perl for Bioinformatics](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000806.do); [Perl and Bioinformatics](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=823275); or [BioPerl](http://bioperl.org/).

I realize that this answer may be TMI; but, if it helps you or others find more appropriate solutions, it served its purpose.

**Edit:**

Based on the comment below, this appears to be a homework question, given the
requirement that the search be accomplished by `StringBuilder.indexOf()`. The following method would accomplish the search accordingly.

```
public List<Integer> findBySb( String seq ) {
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( gene );
    int strIdx = 0;

    while ( strIdx < sb.length() ) {
        int idx = sb.indexOf( seq, strIdx );
        if ( idx == -1 )
            break;
        indices.add( idx );
        strIdx = idx + seq.length();
    }

    return indices;
}
```

The same `indexOf()` approach can used with the string directly.

```
public List<Integer> findByString( String seq ) {
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int strIdx = 0;

    while ( strIdx < gene.length() ) {
        int idx = gene.indexOf( seq, strIdx );
        if ( idx == -1 )
            break;
        indices.add( idx );
        strIdx = idx + seq.length();
    }

    return indices;
}
```

Both `StringBuilder` and `String` use the same static implementation of `String.indexOf()`, thus functionally there is no difference. However,
instantiating a `StringBuilder` just for searching is overkill and a little
more wasteful since it also allocates buffers to manage string operations. I could go on :), but it doesn't add to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, that'll help a lot for the moment to go on with my project(since i need that method in further tasks). Only problem is that my task was to specifically use the indexOf() method of StringBuilder. If I can't figure it out, ur solution will serve the purpose anyway.

Comment: @Smunfr See the additional method added to the solution above for a StringBuilder-based search.